# First proper program, Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, beginner, tic-tac-toe

I'm still pretty new to programming, only been doing it a week. I'm just wondering if I made any glaring mistakes or anything that could be improved code wise?

````
import random

the_board = []
players = [{'type': 'player', 'piece': 'X'},
           {'type': 'player', 'level': 'smart', 'piece': 'O'}]


def print_board(board):
    for i in range(3):
        print(board[i * 3] + '|' + board[i * 3 + 1] + '|' + board[i * 3 + 2], end='')
        print('   ' + str(i * 3) + '|' + str(i * 3 + 1) + '|' + str(i * 3 + 2))
        if i < 2:
            print('-+-+-' + '   ' + '-+-+-')
    print()


def is_win(bo, player):
    # 0 1 2
    # 3 4 5
    # 6 7 8

    for i in range(3):
        return (bo[i * 3] == player and bo[i * 3 + 1] == player and bo[i * 3 + 2] == player) or \
               (bo[i] == player and bo[i+3] == player and bo[i+6] == player) or \
                (i <= 1 and (bo[i*2] == player and bo[4] == player and bo[8-(i*2)] == player))


def check_board(move, player):
    global the_board
    board_copy = the_board.copy()
    board_copy[move] = players[player]['piece']
    print('win')
    return is_win(board_copy, players[player]['piece'])


def ai():
    global players, the_board
    possible_moves = []
    final_move = None

    for i in range(9):
        if the_board[i] == ' ':
            possible_moves.append(i)

    if the_board[4] == ' ' and players[1]['level'] == 'smart':
        the_board[4] = players[1]['piece']
        return

    for i in range(len(possible_moves)):
        board_copy = the_board.copy()
        board_copy[possible_moves[i]] = players[1]['piece']
        if check_board(possible_moves[i], 1):
            the_board[possible_moves[i]] = players[1]['piece']
            print('win')
            return
        elif check_board(possible_moves[i], 0):
            print('lose')
            final_move = possible_moves[i]
        elif players[1]['level'] == 'smart' and final_move is None:
            if possible_moves[i] in [0, 2, 6, 8]:
                print('random')
                final_move = possible_moves[i]
    else:
        if final_move is not None:
            print('other')
            the_board[final_move] = players[1]['piece']
            return
        print('final')
        the_board[possible_moves[random.randint(0, len(possible_moves))]] = players[1]['piece']



def input_validation(option_type, options, choice):
    global the_board
    if option_type == 'number_range':
        if not str.isdigit(choice):
            print('It has to be a number')
            return False
        else:
            choice = int(choice)
        if choice < options[0] or choice > options[1]:
            print('You have to choose a number between 0 and 8')
            return False
        elif (the_board[choice] == 'X' or the_board[choice] == 'O'):
            print('There is already a move there, please try again.')
            return False
        else:
            return True

    if option_type == 'string':
        for i in range(len(options)):
            if choice == options[i]:
                return True
        else:
            print('That is not a valid option, your choices are:')
            for i in range(len(options)):
                print(options[i])
            else:
                print()
            return False


def player_options():
    valid = False
    global players

    while not valid:
        print('Do you want to play the cpu or player?')
        choice = input()
        choice = choice.lower()
        if input_validation('string', ['cpu', 'player'], choice):
            players[1]['type'] = choice
            break

    while not valid and players[1]['type'] == 'cpu':
        print('Do you want smart or dumb ai?:')
        choice = input()
        choice = choice.lower()
        if input_validation('string', ['smart', 'dumb'], choice):
            if choice == 'dumb':
                players[1]['level'] = choice
            break

    # while not valid:
    #     print('Player 1, do you want to be X or O?:')
    #     choice = input()
    #     choice = choice.upper()
    #     if input_validation('string', ['X', 'O'], choice):
    #         if choice == 'O':
    #             players[1]['piece'] = choice
    #         break


def game():
    move = 0
    turn = random.choice([True, False])

    for i in range(9):
        the_board.insert(i, ' ')

    for i in range(9):
        valid = False

        print_board(the_board)
        if is_win(the_board, players[turn]['piece']):
            print_board(the_board)
            print('Player ' + players[turn]['piece'] + ' is the winner!')
            return

        turn ^= True


        if turn == 0 or (players[1]['type'] == 'player' and turn == 1):
            while not valid:
                move = (input('Turn for ' + players[turn]['piece'] + '. Move on which space?: '))
                if input_validation('number_range', [0, 8], move):
                    move = int(move)
                    valid = True
                    the_board[move] = players[turn]['piece']
        elif players[1]['type'] == 'cpu' and turn == 1:
            ai()
    print_board(the_board)
    print('It is a tie!')

def retry():
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        print('Do you want to play again with the same settings? Y or N')
        choice = input()
        choice = choice.upper()
        if input_validation('string', ['Y', 'N'], choice):
            if choice == 'Y':
                game()
            else:
                player_options()
                game()


player_options()
game()
retry()
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Let's upgrade it point-to-point and get a better code at the end:

**0**. I tried to run your program and found several bad user-side behaviors:

U1. MANY unnecessary prints:

```
Do you want to play the cpu or player?
cpu
Do you want smart or dumb ai?:
smart
 | |    0|1|2
-+-+-   -+-+-
 | |    3|4|5
-+-+-   -+-+-
 | |    6|7|8

 | |    0|1|2
-+-+-   -+-+-
 |O|    3|4|5
-+-+-   -+-+-
 | |    6|7|8

Turn for X. Move on which space?: 4
There is already a move there, please try again.
Turn for X. Move on which space?: 5
 | |    0|1|2
-+-+-   -+-+-
 |O|X   3|4|5
-+-+-   -+-+-
 | |    6|7|8

win
win
random
win
win
win
win
win
win
win
win
win
win
win
win
other
O| |    0|1|2
-+-+-   -+-+-
 |O|X   3|4|5
-+-+-   -+-+-
 | |    6|7|8

Turn for X. Move on which space?:
```

Many of them are in `ai()` function:

```
    for i in range(len(possible_moves)):
        board_copy = the_board.copy()
        board_copy[possible_moves[i]] = players[1]['piece']
        if check_board(possible_moves[i], 1):
            the_board[possible_moves[i]] = players[1]['piece']
            print('win')
            return
        elif check_board(possible_moves[i], 0):
            print('lose')
            final_move = possible_moves[i]
        elif players[1]['level'] == 'smart' and final_move is None:
            if possible_moves[i] in [0, 2, 6, 8]:
                print('random')
                final_move = possible_moves[i]
```

We will remove them. If you want, you can import `logging` module and log them to debug stream with `logging.debug(...)`.

U2. You can't just manually quit the game. So let's modify `retry` function:

```
def retry():
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        print('Do you want to play again with the same settings? Y or N (Q to exit)')
        choice = input()
        choice = choice.upper()
        if input_validation('string', ['Y', 'N', 'Q'], choice):
            if choice == 'Y':
                game()
            elif choice == 'Q':
                return
            else:
                player_options()
                game()
```

U3. The game randomly crashes and doesn't react to winning positions.

Look at your `is_win()` code:

```
def is_win(bo, player):
    # 0 1 2
    # 3 4 5
    # 6 7 8

    for i in range(3):
        return (
```

`return` statement immediately exits from the function with a value you wrote to return. So this code will work only for `i == 0`. If you want to check everything and return if there is True anywhere, you should modify your code like this (and, please, use consistent variables! If you are using `board`, use it everywhere for boards. Don't use `board`, `bo` and smth like `b` in different places):

```
def is_win(board, player):
    # 0 1 2
    # 3 4 5
    # 6 7 8

    for i in range(3):
        if (
            (board[i * 3] == player and
             board[i * 3 + 1] == player and
             board[i * 3 + 2] == player)
            or
            (board[i] == player and
             board[i+3] == player and
             board[i+6] == player)
            or
            (i <= 1 and
             (board[i*2] == player and
              board[4] == player and
              board[8-(i*2)] == player))
        ):
            return True
    return False
```

Now we are going to the code directly:

1. Avoid global variables! In 99.99% you don't need them and can easily work without them. Global variables can (and often will) lead you to very hard-to-debug errors. We will eliminate global variables by creating `TicTac` class and converting all functions to class functions (very much code, you will see it later).
2. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Everywhere in your code you have variables like `players[1]['piece']` and `players[1]['level']`. You can create new short variable (especially because we created a class) and use it everywhere. If you will change your `player` structure (for 3rd player, for example), you will not have to change EVERYTHING in your code. We will replace them with `self.ai_level` and `self.ai_X`
3. In `ai()` function you have a line:

`self.the_board[possible_moves[random.randint(0, len(possible_moves))]] = self.ai_X`

`random.randint` can return bounds (e.g. `random.randint(0, 5)` can return both 0 or 5) so this line sometimes raises an error (when you are trying to get the last element of `random.randint`). You can define right bound as `len(possible_moves) - 1` or you can just use `random.choice`:

`self.the_board[random.choice(possible_moves)] = self.ai_X`

4. Some small improvements like:

```
for i in range(9):
    self.the_board.insert(i, ' ')
```

to

`self.the_board = [' '] * 9`

and like it.

So we have a final code. Honestly, it is better to re-write the whole game from scratch but you will realize it only some years later :) This code still not ideal and has many places to improve but it is better than it was.

```
import random

class TicTac(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.the_board = [' '] * 9
        self.players = [
            {'type': 'player', 'piece': 'X'},
            {'type': 'player', 'level': 'smart', 'piece': 'O'}
        ]
        self.ai_level = None
        self.ai_X = None

    def print_board(self, board):
        for i in range(3):
            print(board[i * 3] + '|' + board[i * 3 + 1] + '|' + board[i * 3 + 2], end='')
            print('   ' + str(i * 3) + '|' + str(i * 3 + 1) + '|' + str(i * 3 + 2))
            if i < 2:
                print('-+-+-' + '   ' + '-+-+-')
        print()

    def is_win(self, board, player):
        # 0 1 2
        # 3 4 5
        # 6 7 8

        for i in range(3):
            if (
                (board[i * 3] == player and
                 board[i * 3 + 1] == player and
                 board[i * 3 + 2] == player)
                or
                (board[i] == player and
                 board[i+3] == player and
                 board[i+6] == player)
                or
                (i <= 1 and
                 (board[i*2] == player and
                  board[4] == player and
                  board[8-(i*2)] == player))
            ):
                return True
        return False

    def check_board(self, move, player):
        board_copy = self.the_board.copy()
        board_copy[move] = self.players[player]['piece']
        return self.is_win(board_copy, self.players[player]['piece'])

    def ai(self):
        possible_moves = []
        final_move = None

        for i in range(9):
            if self.the_board[i] == ' ':
                possible_moves.append(i)

        if self.the_board[4] == ' ' and self.ai_level == 'smart':
            self.the_board[4] = self.ai_X
            return

        for i in range(len(possible_moves)):
            board_copy = the_board.copy()
            board_copy[possible_moves[i]] = self.ai_X
            if self.check_board(possible_moves[i], 1):
                self.the_board[possible_moves[i]] = self.ai_X
                return
            elif self.check_board(possible_moves[i], 0):
                final_move = possible_moves[i]
            elif self.ai_level == 'smart' and final_move is None:
                if possible_moves[i] in [0, 2, 6, 8]:
                    final_move = possible_moves[i]
        else:
            if final_move is not None:
                self.the_board[final_move] = self.ai_X
                return
            self.the_board[random.choice(possible_moves)] = self.ai_X

    def input_validation(self, option_type, options, choice):
        if option_type == 'number_range':
            if not str.isdigit(choice):
                print('It has to be a number')
                return False
            else:
                choice = int(choice)
            if choice < options[0] or choice > options[1]:
                print('You have to choose a number between 0 and 8')
                return False
            elif (self.the_board[choice] == 'X' or self.the_board[choice] == 'O'):
                print('There is already a move there, please try again.')
                return False
            else:
                return True

        if option_type == 'string':
            for i in range(len(options)):
                if choice == options[i]:
                    return True
            else:
                print('That is not a valid option, your choices are:')
                for i in range(len(options)):
                    print(options[i])
                else:
                    print()
                return False

    def player_options(self):
        valid = False

        while not valid:
            print('Do you want to play the cpu or player?')
            choice = input()
            choice = choice.lower()
            if self.input_validation('string', ['cpu', 'player'], choice):
                self.players[1]['type'] = choice
                break

        while not valid and self.players[1]['type'] == 'cpu':
            self.ai_X = self.players[1]['piece']
            print('Do you want smart or dumb ai?:')
            choice = input()
            choice = choice.lower()
            if self.input_validation('string', ['smart', 'dumb'], choice):
                if choice == 'dumb':
                    self.players[1]['level'] = choice
                    self.ai_level = choice
                break

    def game(self):
        move = 0
        turn = random.choice([True, False])

        for i in range(9):
            valid = False

            self.print_board(self.the_board)
            if is_win(self.the_board, self.players[0]['piece']) or \
                    is_win(self.the_board, self.players[1]['piece']):
                self.print_board(self.the_board)
                print('Player ' + self.players[turn]['piece'] + ' is the winner!')
                return

            turn ^= True

            if turn == 0 or (self.players[1]['type'] == 'player' and turn == 1):
                while not valid:
                    move = (input('Turn for ' + self.players[turn]['piece'] + '. Move on which space?: '))
                    if self.input_validation('number_range', [0, 8], move):
                        move = int(move)
                        valid = True
                        self.the_board[move] = self.players[turn]['piece']
            elif self.players[1]['type'] == 'cpu' and turn == 1:
                self.ai()
        print('It is a tie!')

    def retry(self):
        valid = False
        while not valid:
            print('Do you want to play again with the same settings? Y or N (Q to exit)')
            choice = input()
            choice = choice.upper()
            if input_validation('string', ['Y', 'N', 'Q'], choice):
                if choice == 'Y':
                    self.game()
                elif choice == 'Q':
                    return
                else:
                    self.player_options()
                    self.game()

game = TicTac()
game.player_options()
game.game()
game.retry()
```